# ¿Cómo puedo saber cuando una tabla de MySQL ha sido actualizada?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos MYSQL para servir una API/RESTful mediante PHP, en principio no uso ningún campo estilo `LastDateUpdate` es decir cuando fue insertada o modificado un recurso.

¿Hay alguna sentencia SQL para obtener la última vez que se a modificado una tabla o la base de datos en general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL (como otros motores) tiene "tablas" que te da información de las "tablas" de tu DB... del esquema (la tabla que necesitas consultar es INFORMATION_SCHEMA) Esto se consulta tambien con SQL

Si puedes ver en la ayuda de MySQL en la parte de [20.23 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html)

Donde puedes leer

> Antes de MySQL 5.7.8, las tablas InnoDB particiones, la columna CREATE_TIME demostró siempre NULL. Esta columna muestra la creación de la tabla correcta hora de dichas tablas en MySQL 5.7.8 y más adelante. (Bug #17299181, Bug #69990)
>
> Comenzando con MySQL 5.7.2, UPDATE_TIME muestra un valor de fecha y hora de la última actualización, INSERT o DELETE en tablas InnoDB no se reparten. Previamente, UPDATE_TIME muestra un valor NULL para tablas InnoDB. El valor de timestamp MVCC, refleja el tiempo COMMIT, que se considera el último tiempo de actualización. Marcas de tiempo no se conservan cuando se reinicia el servidor o cuando la tabla es desalojada de la caché de Diccionario de datos de InnoDB.
>
> La columna UPDATE_TIME también muestra esta información para tablas particionadas de InnoDB en MySQL 5.7.8 y más adelante. Anteriormente esta columna siempre fue nula para estas tablas. (Bug #17299181, Bug #69990)

Un ejemplo de

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'Jedis'
```

Pregunta/Respuesta en SOen

- [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guia

- [20.23 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Devuelve las tablas ordenadas por última modificación:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, UPDATE_TIME 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME desc
```